# Jaxb classes for XML schema 1.1

Tags: jaxb

How can we create the jaxb classes out of XSD which is having schema version 1.1.
"xs:override" give me validation error when I am trying to create java classes

Sample XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="{target namespace}"
    xmlns="{xmlns}"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">

<xs:override schemaLocation="o1_3_2/o1.xsd">  
      <xs:group name="ReferenceDataElementExtension">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="USERPROF" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="FACLPROF" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="STDYPROF" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="TRAINING" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:sequence>
     <xs:group name="ReferenceDataElementExtension">
 </xs:override>
</xs:schema>
```

But while generating classes using xjc command it give validation error:

```
s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'schema' is invalid.  Element 'override' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think XJC (JAXB's schema compiler) supports XML Schema 1.1.

XJC uses the library named [XSOM](https://xsom.java.net/) to process XML Schema. But XSOM does not seem to support `xs:override`. Take a look here:

https://svn.java.net/svn/xsom~sources/trunk/src/xmlschema.rng

No `override`, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is there any workaround for this. Tf we can not use XJC then how can we create java classes out of this xsd